# Ormlite with android and desktop sqlite access

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

I'm trying to set up a design for my android and desktop project which allows me to access the sqlite database with ORMLite on my android server and on my desktop server as well.

Sounds a bit strange to have a server running on android but especially when there is no Internet available that might be useful.

I set up a maven project like that:
androidServer module depends on shared
destopServer module depends on shared

I implemented a user class:

```
@DatabaseTable(daoClass = UserDaoImpl.class)
public class User {
    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)   
    private long id;
    @DatabaseField                       
    private boolean isSuperuser;
    @DatabaseField                      
    private String firstname;
    @DatabaseField                      
    private String lastname;
    @DatabaseField                      
    private String email;
}
```

An interface for the Dao interface:

```
public interface IUserDao extends Dao<User, Long > {
```

And an Implementation for JDBC:

```
public class UserDaoImpl extends BaseDaoImpl<User,Long> implements IUserDao {
    public UserDaoImpl(ConnectionSource connectionSource) throws SQLException {
        super(connectionSource, User.class);
    }
}
```

I'm getting in trouble right now because I have to copy a lot of code for inserts or other stuff. Have you any suggestion to do this in a better way so that I can use the same code (except for the database connection) in both, desktopserver and the androidserver?

Thanks for your thoughts!

Comment: Why do you need to copy a lot of code for inserts?  Why can't you just use the base class' methods?  Also, you don't need to create your own DAO unless you are doing custom DAO functions.  You can just use `DaoManager.createDao(connectionSource, class);`

Comment: Hi the problem is that my DatabaseHelper extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper on the Android side. On the Desktop side I use the DriverManager to get the connection. I thought of an abstract DatabaseHalper in my shared module where I can do the database specific things to use it in my dektop and my android module except for setting up the connection. This isn't possible because of the extend of OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper. But maybe I'm doing something completely wrong.

Comment: I don't understand why `OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper` is getting in the way.  You can get the `connectionSource` from it and instantiate your own DAOs that way.  What am i missing?

Comment: I can't use it in my other desktop module without android dependency.

Comment: No I understand that.  Why can't you use your DAOs in both Android and Desktop?